# 8 Puzzle with Backtracking

Tags: c, recursion, backtracking

I was reading this book from Skiena, Programming Challenges and after the backtracking chapter there was a question about solving the 15-puzzle with backtracking, which I reduce it to 8-puzzle just experimenting. I have this recursive code and I am wondering whether it have a chance to find the solution ever. The code is kind of ugly (be warned):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int arr[20][20]={
    {3,1,2},
    {4,0,5},
    {6,8,7}
};

int moveX[20]={1,1,1,0,0,-1,-1,-1};
int moveY[20]={0,1,-1,1,-1,0,1,-1};
int depth=0;

int findRow(){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(j=0;j<4;j++){
            if(arr[i][j]==0){
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
}

int findCol(){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            if(arr[i][j]==0){
                return j;
            }
        }
    }
}

void print(){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            printf("%i ",arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int isReady(){
    if(arr[0]==1 && arr[1]==2 && arr[2]==3 && arr[3]==4 && arr[4]==5 && arr[5]==6 && arr[6]==7 && arr[7]==8){
        return 1;
    }
    else return 0;
}

void perm(int row,int col,int n){
    if(n>=9){
        print();
        if(isReady())
            printf("Finished");
        depth++;

        return;
    }

    int i=0;int diffX,diffY,temp;
    int r=findRow();
    int c=findCol();
    temp=arr[r][c];
    arr[r][c]=arr[row][col];
    arr[row][col]=temp;
    for(i=0;i<8;i++){
        diffX=row+moveX[i];
        diffY=col+moveY[i];
        if(diffX>=0 && diffX<4 && diffY>=0 && diffY<4){
            perm(diffX,diffY,n+1);
        }
    }
    temp=arr[r][c];
    arr[r][c]=arr[row][col];
    arr[row][col]=temp;
}

int main()
{
    perm(0,0,0);
    return 0;
}
```

My question is, is there a chance with this code to find the solution and second, can anybody how the puzzle can be solved in reasonable time?

Comment: Well no ,it is not working ,in the book it is written ,that it can find solution in 50 steps for 15-puzzle,but I could not find anything on the Web.

Comment: Then *how* is it not working? The more details you can give us about your problem hhe better. For example, does it build? If not then please edit your question to include the *complete* build log. Does it crash? Then please run it in a debugger and at least provide us with a function call stack. Does it give the wrong result? Then for some specified input, what is the *actual* and *expected* output. You can't expect us to just read this much code (can you also please narrow it down to the problematic parts?), and definitely not run it.

Comment: Your `isReady` function should make comparisons of a two-dimensional array, not of a linearised array. (Alternatively, you could `memcmp` with a copy of the desired solution.) Also, check your indices: The 4's should probably be 3's. And why do you move diagonally?

Comment: Yes ,it build and it does not crash,but it is not finding the right combination ,if I remove the print function it is just returning me answer from the OS ,that the program had finished,if the print() is there it is printing a lot of combinations (but not the right one )

Comment: Your double-indexing via `row` and `col` (as function parameters) and `c` and `r` (as calculated by `findCol/Row`) looks a bit fishy, too. Forexample, in the first iteration, you swap (0, 0)  with (1, 1), which is an illegal move.

Comment: Yes ,I fixed this ,I used 1d array at the beginning ant forgot to change it ,but It is still not showing the right answer,I guess it is because the recursion tree is very deep and I need to cut it somehow.

Comment: some functions, like: int findRow(){ only have one (of several) execution paths that actually return a value, however all execution paths must return a value.  Since this does not occur, the compiler should be raising warnings about functions that should return a value, have no return value.

Answer (score 3):

You have five problems.  First, the `isReady` function is incorrect.  It should look like this:

```
int isReady(){
    if(arr[0][0]==1 && arr[0][1]==2 && arr[0][2]==3 &&
            arr[1][0]==4 && arr[1][1]==5 && arr[1][2]==6 &&
            arr[2][0]==7 && arr[2][1]==8){
        return 1;
    }
    else return 0;
}
```

Second, you are exceeding your puzzle bounds with `diffX` and `diffY`.  You need to change this:

```
    if(diffX>=0 && diffX<4 && diffY>=0 && diffY<4){
```

to this:

```
    if(diffX>=0 && diffX<3 && diffY>=0 && diffY<3){
```

Third, your `findRow` function also exceeds the puzzle bounds.  Change all of the `4` to `3`.

Fourth, you should check your victory condition only after you have made your move.  So move your victory check below the swap:

```
temp=arr[r][c];
arr[r][c]=arr[row][col];
arr[row][col]=temp;
// This victory check is now below the move.
if(n>=9){
    print();
    if(isReady())
        printf("Finished");
    depth++;

    return;
}
```

Fifth, you should change your initial call from this:

```
perm(0,0,0);
```

to this:

```
perm(1,1,0);
```

The way you have it, you are always forcing a move to the upper left as your first move.  The modified way keeps the 0 in the center so it doesn't force your first move.  When I ran this code with all of the modifications I made, it found 3 solutions.  When I further modified the code to check for solutions at **any** depth, it found 2 solutions at depth 8 and 3 solutions at depth 9.